# KIF Framework for iOS: Can it simulate touch-and-hold gesture?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automated-tests, integration-testing, kif-framework

How do I simulate a touch-and-hold step on a view using the [KIF-framework for iOS](https://github.com/square/KIF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are functions built into the framework now.  You can use it like this:

`[steps addObject:[KIFTestStep stepToLongPressViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"myView" duration:5]];`

or

`[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToLongPressViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"myView" duration:5]];`

Obviously the first is for adding to a `step` and the second is for a `scenario`.

Comment: How to use this with KIF 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know KIF doesn't emulate gestures. Emulating gestures is really just testing iOS layer stuff anyway. The suggested thing to do is to just call the method that would be invoked for the gesture in your TestStep and go from there.